# $ab-dck_1k_2>0\implies a-ck_2>0$ and $b-dk_1>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Why if $ab-dck_1k_2>0,$ then $a-ck_2>0$ and $b-dk_1>0  {  \\\\\ }?$

It's very unclear.

This is my attempt:

If $a,b,d,c,k_1,k_2>0$ then $ab$ is bigger than $dck_1k_2$. But it does't imply that $a-ck_2>0$ since $b$ could be much bigger than $a$ and $ck_2$  much bigger than $dk_1.$

Comment: Does not hold true unless there are additional conditions on the variables involved. Consider $a=b=c=2, d=k_1=k_2=1$ for example.  Something must be missing from the question.

Comment: @dxiv if all the variables  are positive isn't enough?

Comment: Take $a=3,b=1,c=1,d=2,k_1=1,k_2=1$. We have $ab-dck_1k_2\gt 0$ and $a-ck_2\gt 0$, but $b-dk_1\le 0$.

Comment: @mathlove It was actually a point in $\mathbb R^2$, $\frac{(ab-bck_2)k_1}{ab-dck_1k_2},a(\frac{bk_2-dk_1k_2}{ab-dck_1k_2})$. But my teacher just stated the same that I asked.

Comment: We have $x=\frac{bk_1(a-ck_2)}{ab-dck_1k_1},y=\frac{ak_2(b-dk_1)}{ab-dck_1k_2}$. So, it seems that your teacher supposes that $x\gt 0, y\gt 0$.

Comment: @mathlove yes, and then $a-ck_2>0$